# Using FoxCop 1.36 with ASP.NET MVC Project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I am developing an application in ASP.NET MVC 2. I would like to use FoxCop 1.36. Is there a way to use the foxcop for ASP.NET MVC Projects. If possible, kindly let me know the procedures.

Comment: Or can any one guide me on using dotTrace with ASP.NET MVC2

Comment: its been a long time and no reply... let this question stand closed then.